# Adding strings by converting them to integer and then returning a string

Tags: c, sum, char, c-strings, function-definition

Sorry for such a simple question but i just started C and DSA and found this question on leet code -
Given two non-negative integers, num1 and num2 represented as string, return the sum of num1 and num2 as a string.

You must solve the problem without using any built-in library for handling large integers (such as BigInteger). You must also not convert the inputs to integers directly.

```
#include<stdio.h>

    char *addStrings(char * num1, char * num2){
    int intresult= (int)(num1-'0')+(int)(num2-'0');
    char *result=intresult+'0';
    return result;
}
int main(){
    char *num1="70";
    char *num2="80";
    char *result=addStrings(num1,num2);
    printf("%c\n",result);
    printf("%s\n",result);

    return 0;
}
```

there are many warnings about this and its now working properly.
All the solution were extremely big and complex and thought there would be a simple soltion to such a easy question.
the main problem is with the typecasting.I don't have to use libraries to solve the question.
I found the minimal and best way to typecast is to subtract '0' ascii value = 45 to get the the write integer and add '0' to get the right string but still it won't work.
Hope to get a code answer and a good explanation about typecasting problem too.
Thanks in advance and sorry if you think it's a waste of time.

Comment: It is evident that the function does not make a sense. What are you going to obtain subtracting the character '0' from a pointer like that num1-'0'?

Comment: @DHRUV KABRA, `*num1-'0'+*num2-'0'` works to sum one digit of the strings. Code needs a _loop_, starting from the least significant digit, to sum all the digits - one set at a time.  Also need a _carry_, just like you learned to add in grade school.

Comment: Think about how your function would sum these two: `"123456789012345678901234567890 9988776655443322110099887766"`. How would you sum them with pencil and paper? The question doesn't say you can't use a library: it says you can't  use a **bigint** library.

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question but if you are trying to convert strings to integers use the `strtol()` function.

Answer (score 1):

In the function

```
char *addStrings(char * num1, char * num2){
int intresult= (int)(num1-'0')+(int)(num2-'0');
char *result=intresult+'0';
return result;
```

}

there are much invalid code.

For starters subtracting a character from a pointer like in this expression `(int)(num1-'0')+(int)(num2-'0')` does not make a sense. The both sub-expressions `num1-'0'` and `num2-'0'` have the pointer type `char *` and yield some memory addresses due to the pointer arithmetic. The behavior of such a subtraction from the beginning of an array is undefined.

This declaration

```
char *result=intresult+'0';
```

also does not make a sense. The pointer `result` does not point to a valid object.

You need to allocate dynamically a character array taking into account a possible overflow of the sum of the numbers and in loops fill it.

Here is a demonstration program that shows how the function can be declared and defined.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char * addStrings( const char *s1, const char *s2 )
{
    const unsigned int Base = 10;

    size_t n1 = strlen( s1 );
    size_t n2 = strlen( s2 );

    size_t n = n2 < n1 ? n2 : n1;

    unsigned int carry = 0;

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        carry = !( carry + ( s1[n1-i-1] - '0' ) + ( s2[n2-i-1] - '0' )  < Base );
    }

    for ( size_t i = 0; carry && i < n1 - n; i++ )
    {
        carry = !( s1[n1-n-i-1] - '0' + carry < Base );
    }

    for ( size_t i = 0; carry && i < n2 - n; i++ )
    {
        carry = !( s2[n2-n-i-1] - '0' + carry < Base );
    }

    size_t n3 = ( n1 < n2 ? n2 : n1 ) + carry;
    char *result = malloc( n3 + 1 );

    if ( result != NULL )
    {
        result[n3] = '\0';
        
        carry = 0;

        for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
        {
            unsigned int sum = ( s1[n1-i-1] - '0' ) + ( s2[n2-i-1] - '0' ) + carry;
            result[n3-i-1] = sum % Base + '0'; 
            carry = !( sum  < Base );
        }

        for ( size_t i = 0; i < n1 - n; i++ )
        {
            unsigned int sum = s1[n1-n-i-1] - '0' + carry;
            result[n3-n-i-1] = sum % Base + '0'; 
            carry = !( sum  < Base );
        }

        for ( size_t i = 0; i < n2 - n; i++ )
        {
            unsigned int sum = s2[n2-n-i-1] - '0' + carry;
            result[n3-n-i-1] = sum % Base + '0'; 
            carry = !( sum  < Base );
        }

        if( carry ) result[0] = '1';
    }

    return result;
}

int main( void ) 
{
    char *sum = addStrings( "1", "99999999999999999999" ); 
    if ( sum ) puts( sum );
    free( sum );

    sum = addStrings( "99999999999999999999", "2" ); 
    if ( sum ) puts( sum );
    free( sum );

    sum = addStrings( "1", "2" ); 
    if ( sum ) puts( sum );
    free( sum );
}
```

The program output is

```
100000000000000000000
100000000000000000001
3
```

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Thanks. It was a typo.